# Center Axes in oxyplot

Tags: plot, charts, axes, oxyplot

I want to draw a chart like image below with oxyplot, the problem is i don't know how to draw axis (with values) at value 50.

[image: example]

Code :

```
        var model = new PlotModel { Title = "EllipseAnnotations" };
        model.Axes.Add( new LinearAxis {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
            Minimum = 20,
            Maximum = 80,
            PositionAtZeroCrossing = true,
            ExtraGridlines = new[] { 50.0 },
            ExtraGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dash
        });
        model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis {
            Position = AxisPosition.Left,
            Minimum = 20,
            Maximum = 80,
            PositionAtZeroCrossing = true,
            ExtraGridlines = new[] { 50.0 }
        });
        model.Annotations.Add(new EllipseAnnotation { X = 50, Y = 50, Width = 10, Height = 10, Fill = OxyColors.LightGray, Stroke = OxyColors.Black, StrokeThickness = 1 });
        model.Annotations.Add(new EllipseAnnotation { X = 50, Y = 50, Width = 30, Height = 30, Fill = OxyColors.Transparent, Stroke = OxyColors.Black, StrokeThickness = 1 });
        model.Annotations.Add(new EllipseAnnotation { X = 50, Y = 50, Width = 60, Height = 60, Fill = OxyColors.Transparent, Stroke = OxyColors.Black, StrokeThickness = 1 });

        //model.Annotations.Add(new EllipseAnnotation { X = 50, Y = 50, Width = 20, Height = 20, Fill = OxyColors.Aqua, Stroke = OxyColors.Black, StrokeThickness = 2 });
        //model.Annotations.Add(new EllipseAnnotation { X = 30, Y = 20, Width = 20, Height = 20, Fill = OxyColors.Red, Stroke = OxyColors.Black, StrokeThickness = 2 });
        //model.Annotations.Add(new EllipseAnnotation { X = 25, Y = 30, Width = 20, Height = 20, Fill = OxyColors.Blue, Stroke = OxyColors.Black, StrokeThickness = 2 });
```

and this is how it look

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you intend, but adding

```
        model.Annotations.Add(new TextAnnotation
        {
            TextPosition = new DataPoint(50, 50),
            Text = "50",
            TextHorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            TextVerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Middle,
            StrokeThickness = 0
        });
```

to your setup code will produce this

[image]

Comment: Thank you. that is not what i was exactly looking for but it solve the problem. i wanted to draw left and bottom axes at center (50) ... Could you help me with another thing ? Is there a way that don't render the gridline outside the larger EllipseAnnotation ?

Comment: @behrooz Glad I could help. I'm not sure what you mean. Could you make an image and show/paint what you mean? If you post that as a new question others may benefit from it too.

Comment: ok i asked new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826731/how-to-dont-render-gridline-outside-ellipseannotation-in-oxyplot)

Comment: @behrooz I had a look but unfortunaltely I have no idea how to achieve that. But thank you for the credits ;)